# Inverse of a Fourier matrix

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions, fourier-analysis

I am trying to find the inverse of a Fourier matrix but I am getting confusing results.

If `R` is a Fourier matrix, then `Inverse[R].R` should return the identity matrix, but instead it is giving me the complicated result below. When I try for even order ones, it is working as expected (giving me the identity) but odd ones are giving me this result. Can someone please tell me what I am missing?

[image: Inverse operation]

Comment: Have you tried `FullSimplify`? Cannot test right now, though

Answer (score 4):

You simply need to simplify your result using `Simplify` (dimensions < 4) or `FullSimplify` (larger), as appropriate:

```
Inverse@FourierMatrix[3].FourierMatrix[3] // Simplify
(* Out: {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}} *)

FullSimplify[Inverse@FourierMatrix[7].FourierMatrix[7]] == IdentityMatrix[7]
(* Out: True *)
```

As you can see, an identity matrix is obtained in both cases.

(Thanks to Bob Hanlon for pointing out the need for `FullSimplify` in larger cases).

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks for pointing that out. I added it to the answer.